# getPreferences() reference to class name used by getSharedPreferences()

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to use preferences from a Dialog, and have been having some difficulty. The rest of my application just uses the `getPreferences()` dialog, and doesn't seem to have any problems at all. However, a Dialog can't call a `getPreferences()`, and for some reason I don't have access to the base Activity. But I've come to a solution, [from the SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29), but I need one quick answer to have it.

The SDK states that "This simply calls the underlying `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.". If I can get the activity's class name. I have access to context, which includes [`getApplicationInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationInfo%28%29). There are a variety of names here. My question is, is one of the names that comes from `getApplicationInfo()` the same as the value that `getPreferences()` passes to `getSharedPreferences()` as the class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better, and this is now the way I use them, is to use this:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```

This gets the right preferences, without needing to do anything complicated.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was using this as the application name across the board:

```
getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName
```

The context is almost universally available, and this name should be consistent for all classes in the program.